# VBA to copy data from multiple workbooks into another workbook 'same worksheet' then update format color and font

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that works for me if I am copying each file separately.

My 3 files (file names: Jap, Trap, Bart) from which I want to copy from are opened. The sheet name 'Names' is the same for all 3 files.

The file I want to copy the data into is also opened
In worksheet name 'Data' I want the code to go to the next empty row and copy and paste the data from the 3 open files individually.
So the script will run through each file until all workbooks data are copied over. Then I want the format for the data to be 'no color' and the font to be 'Arial 10'.

I want to learn how to do this also.
So, assist me with understanding how to do it while you modify my code; thanks in advance.

**My current Code:**

```vb
Sub Update_Current_Revenue_Data()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim CopyLastRow As Long
Dim DestLastRow As Long

    Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Jap.xlsm").Worksheets("Names")
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Consol.xlsm").Worksheets("Data")
    CopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    DestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    wsCopy.Range("A2:N" & CopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("A" & DestLastRow)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a reusable sub to do the copy

```vb
' set up a reusable sub
Sub Update_Current_Revenue_Data(wbCopy As Workbook, SourceSheetName As String, wsDest As Worksheet, FromRow As Long, NumColumns As Long)
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim CopyLastRow As Long
    Dim DestRow As Long
    Dim data As Variant
    
    ' Check that sheet exists
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wsCopy = wbCopy.Worksheets(SourceSheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not wsCopy Is Nothing Then
        CopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        DestRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row + 1
    
        data = wsCopy.Range(wsCopy.Cells(FromRow, 1), wsCopy.Cells(CopyLastRow, NumColumns)).Value
        
        wsDest.Cells(DestRow, 1).Resize(UBound(data, 1), UBound(data, 2)).Value = data
    End If
End Sub
```

Then Call the sub for each book to copy
Several options are included to select the books.  Pick one.

```vb
'Call the sub
Sub Demo()
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim SourceSheetName As String
    
    Set wbDest = Workbooks("Consol.xlsm")
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("Data")
    
    SourceSheetName = "Names"
    
' ===================================
'   Option 1: explicit sheets
    ' update extensions if necassary
    Update_Current_Revenue_Data Workbooks("Jap.xlsx"), SourceSheetName, wsDest, 2, 14
    Update_Current_Revenue_Data Workbooks("Trap.xlsx"), SourceSheetName, wsDest, 2, 14
    Update_Current_Revenue_Data Workbooks("Bart.xlsx"), SourceSheetName, wsDest, 2, 14
    
' ===================================
'   Option 2: Specify collection of books
    Dim CopyBooks As Collection
    Dim wbCopy As Workbook
    
    Set CopyBooks = New Collection
    CopyBooks.Add Workbooks("Jap.xlsx")
    CopyBooks.Add Workbooks("Trap.xlsx")
    CopyBooks.Add Workbooks("Bart.xlsx")
    
    For Each wbCopy In CopyBooks
        Update_Current_Revenue_Data wbCopy, SourceSheetName, wsDest, 2, 14
    Next
    
' ===================================
'   Option 3: Copy from all books except wbDest
    Dim wbCopy As Workbook
    
    For Each wbCopy In Workbooks
        If Not wbCopy Is wbDest Then
            Update_Current_Revenue_Data wbCopy, SourceSheetName, wsDest, 2, 14
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. I see you are a Teacher; appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

### Multiple Workbooks to One

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub updateCurrentRevenueData()

    ' Define Source Workbook Names.
    Dim sNames As Variant
    sNames = Array("Jap.xlsm", "Trap.xlsm", "Bart.xlsm")
    
    ' Define Destination First Available Cell Range.
    With Workbooks("Consol.xlsm").Worksheets("Data")
        Dim dFirst As Range
        Set dFirst = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With
    ' Define Destination Current First Cell Range.
    Dim dCell As Range
    Set dCell = dFirst
    
    ' Declare additional variables for upcoming 'For Each Next' loop.
    Dim sName As Variant  ' Current Source Workbook Name
    Dim sLastRow As Long  ' Current Source Last Row
    Dim sRng As Range     ' Current Source Copy Range
    Dim dRows As Long     ' Destination Total Number of Rows of Copied Data
    
    ' Iterate Source Workbooks.
    For Each sName In sNames
        ' Define Current Copy Range.
        With Workbooks(sName).Worksheets("Names")
            sLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set sRng = .Range("A2:N" & sLastRow)
        End With
        
        With sRng
            ' Copy Current Copy Range to Destination Worksheet.
            .Copy dCell
            ' If you only need values, you should rather use the following line
            ' instead of '.Copy dCell'. Then you also don't need
            ' '.Interior.Color = xlNone'.
            'dCell.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = sRng.Value
            ' Count Destination Total Number of Rows of Copied Data.
            dRows = dRows + .Rows.Count
            ' Define Destination Current First Cell Range.
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(.Rows.Count)
        End With
    Next sName
    
    ' Apply formatting to Total Destination Range.
    With dFirst.Resize(dRows, sRng.Columns.Count)
        .Interior.Color = xlNone
        With .Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 10
            '.Bold = True
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to modify my code easily and follow along.

Comment: Hi, I have a follow on to this question. Your code works perfectly. I am want to add a filter to sNames column L, the filter should be greater than a specific number I want to enter in a message box prompt. So before copy data I want to filter and the copy over only the range specified in the filter.